# Is adding values with tf.concat slow in for-loops?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, for-loop, tensorflow2.0

Im using tensorflow 2.0 and try to speed up my training by optimizing my code a little bit.

I run my model batchwise and want to safe the results from each batch to have all results at the end of one epoch in one tensor.

This is how my code looks like:

```
...
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):

    # this vector shall hold all results for one epoch
    predictions_epoch = tf.zeros(0,)
   
    for batch in tf_dataset: 
        # get prediction with predictions_batch.shape[0] euqals batch_size
        predictions_batch = model(batch)   
        
        # Add the batch result to the previous results
        predictions_epoch = tf.concat(predictions_batch, predictions_epoch)
        
        # DO SOME OTHER STUFF LIKE BACKPROB
        ...

    # predictions_epoch.shape[0] now equals number of all samples in dataset
    with writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.histogram(name='predictions', data=predictions_epoch, step=epoch)
```

Lets assume, one prediction is just a scalar value. So `predictions_batch` is a tensor with shape=[batchsize,].

This way of doing the concaternation just works fine.

Now my question is:
Does this `tf.concat()` operation slow down my whole training? I also used `tf.stack()`for this purpose, but it seems like no difference in speed.

I wonder, because once I worked with Matlab, adding new values to a Vector (and hence change its size) within a for-loop was extremly slow. Initializing the vector with zeros and then assign values in the loop was way more efficient regarding speed.

Is this also true for tensorflow? Or is there another more 'proper' way of doing something like adding tensors together in a for-loop which is more clean or faster?
I did not find any alternative solution online.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is not the most recommendable way to do it. It is better to simply add each tensor to a list and concatenate them once at the end:

```py
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
    predictions_batches = []
    for batch in tf_dataset:
        predictions_batch = model(batch)
        predictions_batches.append(predictions_batch)
        # ...
    predictions_epoch = tf.concat(predictions_batches)
```

You can also use a [`tf.TensorArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray), which may be better if you want to decorate the code with [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function).

```py
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
    # Pass arguments as required
    # If the number of batches is know or an upper bound
    # can be estimated use that and dynamic_size=False
    predictions_batches = tf.TensorArray(
        tf.float32, INTIAL_SIZE, dynamic_size=True, element_shape=[BATCH_SIZE])
    i = tf.constant(0)
    for batch in tf_dataset:
        predictions_batch = model(batch)
        predictions_batches = predictions_batches.write(i, predictions_batch)
        i += 1
        # ...
    predictions_epoch = predictions_batches.concat()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I will try both approches and make a speed comparison.

Comment: Is there any way to concatenate the array without flattening?  tf.TensorArray's concat() doesn't seem to have an axis parameter.

Comment: @MortenGrum No, `tf.TensorArray` only allows for concatenating or stacking on the first dimension (although you can always [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) the tensor after to reorder the axes). If you want to concatenate across a different dimension, you'd need to transpose the data you put into the array to make that the first dimension (and then transpose back the result if necessary).

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa! Your suggested alternatives are more or less what I now have in place and yes it works fine too.